# Equivalent to SelectedIndexChanged in VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to convert some code from C# to VB.NET so i can use it within my project. However one bit i cannot convert is when it comes to my ComboBox control. In C# i can use

```
combobox.selectedindexchanged
```

However when i try to use this in VB.NET it says it is an event and i cannot use it within a Sub, however i need to use it for an IF statement when the value of my combobox changes, is there a VB.NET equivalent or anything else i can use to solve the problem?

Comment: SelectedIndexChanged is an event and not a method.  It is fired when the user clicks a different item.  Its not a VB thing, its a Windows thins.  To manually set the selecteditem use Selecteditem or SelectedIndex or SelectedValue for ListBoxes and Combo depending on what is in them

Comment: The description of what you're trying to do is very unclear.  Can you provide a more complete example?

Comment: I am creating a ComboBox within my code, so i cannot access it through the design view, so if i wanted to carry out a piece of code when the value of the combo box changes, what code would i use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF you are creating the `ComboBox` dynamically and want to handle when the selected value changes (as per your comment) then this is the way to go:

```
Dim cb As New ComboBox()
Addhandler cb.SelectedValueChanged, AddressOf cbe_SelectedValueChanged
Addhandler cb.SelectedIndexChanged , AddressOf cbe_SelectedIndexChanged
....

Private Sub cbe_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub cbe_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub
```

More information on the available events:

[ComboBox Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox_events%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

**C# :**

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, 
        System.EventArgs e)
    {

// Code here

    }
```

**VB : **

```
 Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, _
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

 //   'Code here

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The visual basic equivalent of the C#:

```cs
object.event += handler
```

is [`AddHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yyk8z93%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
AddHandler object.event, handler
```

(And similarly, `-=` becomes `RemoveHandler`)

The documentation for [Lambda Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx) shows how to combine `AddHandler` and lambdas in VB, e.g.:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AddHandler Button1.Click, 
        Async Sub(sender1, e1)
            ' ExampleMethodAsync returns a Task.
            Await ExampleMethodAsync()
            TextBox1.Text = vbCrLf & "Control returned to Button1_ Click."
        End Sub
End Sub
```